# GeoRSS aggregators?

Tags: rss, georss, aggregators

Are there still any functioning GeoRSS aggregators out there?

I'm basically thinking of a blog aggregator, but specifically one that only indexes posts that have coordinates associated with them.

Comment: At Superfeedr we monitor this quite closely... but the truth is there are exteremely few RSS feeds these days which we see support GeoRSS :(

Comment: That's sad indeed. Do you allow for obtaining matching articles based on a geolocation and a radius?